# Identifying Deprecated IAM Roles in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

In AWS, how do you identify services using deprecated IAM roles?

Preferably, I want automate this as part of an enterprise security scan.

I'm not finding anything via Google search.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "deprecated IAM roles"? Do you mean *unused* IAM roles? Because IAM roles don't become deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

[Access Analyzer](https://aws.amazon.com/iam/features/analyze-access/) is designed to assist identifying security issues in IAM. IAM also includes last accessed data that can be [used to find unused permissions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_access-advisor-example-scenarios.html).